# Rascal/Eclipse integration error (Unable to load Rascal perspective in Eclipse Kepler)

Tags: eclipse, rascal

I installed Eclipse and Rascal as explained on the Rascal download page (http://www.rascal-mpl.org/start/).

However, when I open the Rascal perspective I get the following error in the Rascal Navigator: "Failed to create the part's controls".

Furthermore, in the error log I get messages like:

Error
Sat Mar 22 11:26:48 CET 2014
Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/ElementContainer/selectedElement/SET] to handler org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler@37196d53

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed

I installed:

- Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers (Kepler Service release 2) (eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700).
- Java JDK 8 (also tried with Java JDK 7).
- Installed Rascal using the update site.

Which Eclipse version will work with the Rascal plugin?

Comment: Hi Jeroen! I guess this question is better asked on github, or as an issue. Rascal should work with Keppler fine. You might try in an empty workspace to create a new project. If that works, then I believe I know what the problem is. Could you upload a stack trace to github issues here? <https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been reported and fixed. Until a new release is available I suggest resetting the perspective as a quick fix. (https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/issues/484)

Comment: Resetting didn't work. Re-opening the Rascal perspective worked.